# Why are post, get and put needed on top of HTTPS protocol?

Tags: server, http, webserver, user-agent, request

I understand that the HTTP protocol, especially of the secured type, secured with some data encryption method such as TLS and certified with some SSL certification, is the main way to transfer data in the world wide web.

Well, if so,
Why are post, get and put needed on top of HTTPS protocol`?:`

- Why acting by the HTTP(S) protocol isn't enough for requesting and serving data and another layer is needed on top of that as I described?
- Why, when we or others (say, a program) interact with a webserver, the data is both requested and served (if at all) in different methods such as `post`, `get` and `put` (and maybe also `delete`?) on top of HTTPS protocol?

<sub>An answer will let me better maintain my websites in general.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where this is coming from.   Those methods are part of the HTTP/HTTPS protocol, not "on top of it".

Comment: Hello ; do you say that post, get, put (and also `delete`?) are part of HTTP/HTTPS model and not something external to it? If so, an answer explaining where I was wrong would be helpful PMO.

Comment: Crap, I have just saw the question was closed; well, AOTM I can't recognize how to improve it.

Comment: They are part of the HTTP/HTTPS model and not external to it.  They are defined in [section 9 of the HTTP 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: It looks like this may answer your question: [What is the need of methods like GET and POST in the HTTP protocol?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125226/what-is-the-need-of-methods-like-get-and-post-in-the-http-protocol)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yep; is it good for us the community by mean of SEO if this session becomes a duplicate or deleted? I assume duplicate due to searching the question directly.